# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'location.state'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-router, react-hooks

I have passed id as state one function

```
 <Link 
    className="title"
    id="titles" 
    to={{
         pathname: "/postDetail",
         state: { id:story.objectID }                                
       }}
   >
   {story.title}
</Link>
```

below is the child function

```
const location = useLocation();
const { id } = location.state;

useEffect(() => {

    const link = `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/items/${id}`

    const getPost = async () => {

        await fetch(link)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const post = data;
            setPost(post);
            setLoading(false);
        });           
    }

    getPost();
}, []);
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong someone said to move `const { id } = location.state;`
inside useEffect() .I tried that but it still gives me same error.
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const location = useLocation();
const { id } = location.state;

useEffect(() => {

    const link = `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/items/${id}`

    const getPost = async () => {

        await fetch(link)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const post = data;
            setPost(post);
            setLoading(false);
        });           
    }

    getPost();
}, [id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const location = useLocation();
const { id } = location.state;

useEffect(() => {

    const link = `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/items/${id}`

    const getPost = async () => {

        await fetch(link)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const post = data;
            setPost(post);
            setLoading(false);
        });           
    }

    getPost();
}, [id, setPost, setLoading]);
```

The dependency missing is for everything you used from outside of  that function.

In the future React is trying to write that dependency for you, but for now you just have to identify all of them and add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

### **It's an [Eslint Rule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks), and this plugin is included by default in `create-react-app`**

The rule force you to put any variable that possibly changes during render to your dependency to prevent `stale data` reference

You should put `id` to your dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const link = `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/items/${id}`

    const getPost = async () => {

        await fetch(link)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const post = data;
            setPost(post);
            setLoading(false);
        });           
    }

    getPost();
}, [id]);
```

**OR disable it by adding: `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`**

But is not recommended to disable any eslint rules.